# How to send a trigger duration via email in zabbix

Tags: linux, email, action, alert, zabbix

I have created an Action in zabbix which sends an email alert when the zabbix agent is not accessible for a period of time on a host. It also sends a recovery email after it gets accessible again. I want to send the down time duration in the recovery email. I thought I can use {TRIGGER.DURATION} such as other built in macros {TRIGGER.NAME} and {TRIGGER.STATUS} , but it didn't worked!! Is there any way to do that in zabbix?
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself:D. It is {EVENT.AGE}. It is useful for the ones who want to send downtime duration in their alerts. There are also {EVENT.TIME} and {EVENT.DATE} for sending date and time.